# Some conditional programming in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to build a little workout log in Excel.  I have a drop down list that allows me to pick which muscle group I exercised that day(legs, chest, back, etc.) and I have unique spreadsheet for each group in different worksheets.  I am wanting to be able to choose a muscle group and have that specific spreadsheet pop up right next to it.

Is this possible?  Will it also bring over any formatting/borders?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds feasible to me, with a bit of VBA. If you are opening another spreadsheet,then its formatting will not be modified.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I will try and mess with it and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: I don't understand "unique spreadsheet ... in different worksheets". Does each group have its own worksheet in the same workbook, or its own workbook, or what?  Also, can you reserve the same spot in each worksheet for the dropdown to live in? Also, please explain further about "Will it also bring over any formatting/borders?". Do you want new sheets to be added and formatted automatically for new groups?

Answer (score 1):

Try this for an idea for you to refine further.  I have assumed two worksheets and an ActiveX combobox, which I have called `cmbMGrp`, on worksheet 1 (WorkOut).

One called **WorkOut**

[image: Tab Workout]
This contains your combobox 'dropdown' and the area to the right for the exercise schedule.

and one called **Exercises**

[image: Tab Exercises]
This contains the exercise schedule for each muscle group.

Add the following two bits of code to the Sheet module (WorkOut) i.e. the sheet that contains the combobox.

```
Private Sub cmbMGrp_Change()

    Select Case cmbMGrp.Value
        Case Is = "Biceps"
            stCol = 1
        Case Is = "Legs"
            stCol = 5
        Case Is = "Chest"
            stCol = 9
        Case Is = "Back"
            stCol = 13
        Case Else
            stCol = 0
    End Select

    If stCol > 0 Then
        With Sheets("Exercises")
            lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, stCol).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range(.Cells(1, stCol), .Cells(lrow, stCol).Offset(0, 2)).Copy _
                  Destination:=Sheets("Workout").Range("I3")
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmbMGrp_GotFocus()
    With Sheets("Workout")
        lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range(.Cells(3, 9), .Cells(lrow, 9).Offset(0, 2)).Clear
    End With
End Sub
```

You should be able to match the code to the layouts I have used for this example, shown in the images.  Change these to suit your requirements.

Comment: Thumbs up for thorough answer, but I'm afraid this might be too complicated for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that for your task, you should forget dropdowns. Simply make one table, with rows corresponding to the days, and columns to exercises. You can easily group exercises by muscle groups. Eg. leg might contain flexors, extensors (quadriceps), ass (gluteus), calf (gastrocnemius) etc. Or you can name exercises by the machines you use. Keep it simple in one table, too much programming will distract you from your health effort, which is your real goal.

Btw. I'm quite good in Excel and have done quite amazing things with it, but I tell you, if you value your physical fitness, stay away from its Visual Basic.